# SIGSEGV Segmentation fault when entering wrong file name?

Tags: c++, file, io, segmentation-fault

I've been working on a new "dog simulator" app and I've implemented a function to load an existing file containing a dog and its owner (along with a bunch of numbers for age, snack-counter etc.). Whenever I enter an incorrect file name, the program fails and jumps to this section:

```
std::string dog_name;

if (owner.dog != nullptr) dog_name = owner.dog->name;
else dog_name = "none";
```

I implemented this to set a default parameter to the dog's name in the owner's "print" function.

I have a folder called "dogs" in which I store all saved text files. This is the code I use for finding the current work directory as well as stitching it together with the file name and the folder's directory:

```
std::ifstream load;

    std::cout << "\nEnter file name to load: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, file_name);

    lowercase(file_name); // My own function to set everything to lowercase.

    std::filesystem::path cwd = std::filesystem::current_path();
    std::string dir = cwd.string();

    dir.erase(dir.find("\\cmake"));
    dir += "\\dogs\\";

    std::string path = dir + file_name + ".txt";

    load.open(path);

    if (load) {
        std::getline(load, dog.name);

        load >> dog.age;
    ...
```

I am suspecting that it has something to do with the pointer "dog* dog" in my owner-class, but I honestly have no idea how to work around this. Here is the code for my owner-class:

```
class dog;

class owner {
public:
    std::string name;
    int age;

    dog* dog;

    // Counters
    int poop_counter;
    int good_points;
};
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

EDIT:
I managed to fix the problem. I added default constructors for both the dog and the owner which resolved the issue:

```
owner::owner() {
    this->name = "none";
    this->age = 0;
    this->dog = nullptr;
    this->poop_counter = 0;
    this->good_points = 0;
}
```

Comment: Where do you initialise `owner::dog`?

Comment: A [mcve] would be very helpful.  Particular attention to the *minimal* part, and *reproducible*.

Comment: You are using `getline` and the extraction operator (`>>`) together, which will cause problems. But at a higher level, you have written too much code before testing any of it.

Comment: Your suspicions are likely correct; however because the shown code is not a [mre], it's not possible to determine what the problem is.